# Android FragmentPagerAdapter Passing Wrong Position to My Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Relevant Code:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Nachrichten";
            case 1:
                return "Sport";
            case 2:
                return "Kultur";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        Log.d("onCreateView()","Section number: " + getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));

        if(Feeds.size() != 0) {
            try {
                NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(Nachrichtenleicht.getAppContext(), Feeds.get(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Whenever I click on tab 1 ("Nachrichten" - News) the number 1 is logged, and the correct feed is displayed.

Whenever I click on tab 2 ("Sport") the number 3 is logged, and nothing is displayed.

Whenever I click on tab 3 ("Kultur" - Culture) nothing is logged, and the correct feed is displayed.

I know that all of the feeds have correctly been populated because I have tried switching around the order in the networking code, and the "Sport" feed would show in places 1 or 3, but nothing would show in spot 2. I have also tried getting the current position from the view pager to no avail.

Comment: Hi @ThatJavaScriptGuy did you come up with solution? I am also facing simillar problem.